# Build Spring Roo / Export maven project with Eclipse Export -> Runnable JAR file

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, m2eclipse, spring-roo

I have Maven project created with Spring roo in STS 2.5.1.RELEASE (It is Eclipse 3.6.1 + Spring tools + m2eclipse). I have second simple Java project on build path. Everything is working ok within Eclipse.

Now the problem is to build. I cannot do so with maven, because it also requires that referenced project is maven project. For referenced project I just use Eclipse Export -> Runnable JAR file to export and generate ant file for next build.

Doing so for first project, I get runtime error, even though META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml is both is .jar and in the folder next to .jar

```
2011-02-19 13:58:39,135-org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
2011-02-19 13:58:39,405-org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [rsrc:com/company/test/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:com/company/test/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:com/company/test/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:204)
```

Referenced project is under heavy development, and I cannot move, refactor it or change its nature.
Maven project with Spring roo is parallel version to be developed.

How to build maven project with included eclipse project?

Example. 
Project /RooInheritanceMaven has project /RooInheritanceJava on its (eclipse) build path.

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/RooInheritanceJava"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is incompatibility between Eclipse Export to Executable JAR and Spring.
To be more exact it is

```
org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
```

Similar provlem was before. see

[#SPR-3815  Classloader problem - Spring Projects Issue Tracker](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3815)

try

```
jar -tf PersonApp.jar >PersonApp.jar.txt
```

The solution is to extract .classes and all stuff from jar into folder

```
jar xf PersonApp.jar
```

and run as

```
set CLASSPATH=D:\TEMP\KDF.MSSQL\antlr-2.7.6.jar;D:\TEMP\KDF.MSSQL\aopalliance-1.0.jar; <... all jar dependecies listed>
java com/company/PersonApp
```

Comment: " The solution is to extract .classes and all stuff from jar into folder ", 

this statement worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Look at onejar-maven-plugin http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/22/executable-jar-with-onejar-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Roo command

```
perform package
```

to get your application bundled - so that you can deploy it into your own container.